# Is it possible to use spring boot with TestNG?

Tags: spring-boot, testng

Most of the examples and documentation of testing Spring Boot use JUnit.

Is there an official example of testing Spring Boot with TestNG?

Comment: This question is far too broad. Do you have specific questions about TestNG? Have you tried writing tests in TestNG. Have you tried writing code in spring boot?

Comment: As the answer highlights, most of the examples and documentation use JUnit. Maybe it just needs rewording to say "Is there an official example of using TestNG with Spring Boot"

Comment: Found a good example to implement Spring Boot + TestNG -http://www.javainuse.com/spring/springboot_testng

Answer (score 4):

There is a sample project with spring boot and TestNG:

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-testng

It's one of multiple sample projects provided by spring. You can refer to the Spring Test documentation here.

https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.0.5.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/testing.html

Unfortunately (for TestNG users) most of the guides and documentation available show examples with JUnit, but the integration testing utilities of spring boot should work regardless of the testing framework used

Comment: @SirThompson Github link is dead.

Comment: @sumit good catch. Unfortunately the project seems to have vanished, and there are no other TestNG samples in sight :/ a bit of googling should be enough though